# Trying to find a way to send distributor emails depending on postal code through php

Tags: php, database, html, email, location

I have a client that is a tobacco company that has distributors throughout the country. I am looking to write a script that will allow me to distinguish which distributor, in which states, to send the email to depending solely on which state the postal code is part of. I know i can write the email portion of the script, but i need a way to find the location and send that email to that distributor specifically.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A google search for a zipcode database should help you. You could add it as a table to your own database, search it for zipcode and send the email accordingly....